# NullPointer Exception when using NERClassifierCombiner in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using NERClassifierCombiner in CoreNLP to combine RegexNERSequenceClassifier and CRFClassifier.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.RegexNERSequenceClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String basePath = "some_base_path";
        String filename = basePath + "input.txt";
        String inputText = IOUtils.slurpFile(filename);

        String mucClassifierPath = basePath +  "english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
        String connlClassifierPath = basePath + "english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

        CRFClassifier classifier_muc = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(mucClassifierPath);
        CRFClassifier classifier_connl = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(connlClassifierPath);

        String mappingPath = basePath + "regexner.rules";
        RegexNERSequenceClassifier regexNERSequenceClassifier = new RegexNERSequenceClassifier(mappingPath, true, true, null);

        NERClassifierCombiner combinedNERClassifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false, false, classifier_connl, classifier_muc, regexNERSequenceClassifier);

        String output = combinedNERClassifer.classifyToString(inputText);
        System.out.println(output);

        return;

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace of the exception which is thrown when the classifyToText method is called.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.labels(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:286)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.mergeDocuments(ClassifierCombiner.java:334)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.classify(ClassifierCombiner.java:481)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.classifyWithGlobalInformation(NERClassifierCombiner.java:273)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.classify(NERClassifierCombiner.java:268)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyObjectBank(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:481)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classify(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:441)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

PS: I can't use the CoreNLP Pipeline need to merge RegexNER with existing CRFClassifier in Production.

Comment: Check the code at AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:286

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in CoreNLP. John Bauer (aka AngledLuffa) has fixed it. https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/1160